# Segmentation of data set based on two variables into 4 segments

Tags: python, machine-learning, logic, cluster-analysis, data-science

I have data set which contains search words, totalsearch count and total search phrases used. Its something like this:

```
Sno        SearchWord        TotalSearch       TotalsearchPhrases
 1          Ball-e              100                  10
 2          Apple               897                  4
 3          Deutsche            1500                 21
 4          Microsoft           981                  7
 5          Holochen             30                  1
 6          Kamazai              20                  10
```

So basically,

- **Total search stands** for number of times that company was searched for
  in a month
- **Total search phrases** means what unique words were used to    search
  for that company (*Due, dtsche, Duetch etc for Deutsche and so on*)

I want to segment this data which consists of 10000+ companies into 4 categories:

1. High Total Searches and High Total search phrases used
2. High Total Searches and Low Total search phrases used
3. Low Total Searches and High Total search phrases used
4. Low Total Searches and Low Total search phrases used

I am getting confused in deciding the threshold for these 4 criteria, is there a way I can leverage Machine learning to automatically assign the threshold using clustering or anything?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe this can be done.  From your question, I assume you are asking the following:

Given a n x 4 vector [n, search word, total company search, total search word use], you must divide into 4 categories you have specified above.

In order to do this, you must build some submodules to break the problem down.

**1st Module: Classifier**

You must first identify the number of unique companies in your list. Then you must identify common search phrases used to identify each unique company.  To do this, you need to build a supervised learning classifier.

Labels = Companies

Feature = Input into search bar

So:  Labels = f(Feature)

**2nd Module**

Then you must specify what you consider as high and low total search and search phrase.  You can easily do this by finding the mean or median of the search phrases or total search.  Then all the companies above would be in one cluster, the rest would be in the rest.

So first, split your data on half by seeing which companies are below the median total search, half would be above the median.  Then for each half, you then split them in half.  This time, by the medial total search phrases used.  For any new data, allocate them to the proper group depending on their total search and total search phrase.

With this, you can get 4 separate clusters.  Also, you can re-run the clustering algorithm after every 1000 new data points.  So then, your data will always be properly organized.